# codeigniter v4 num_rows() Call to undefined method

Tags: codeigniter, row

Num rows not found in the documentation Codeigniter 4.

My method in my model:

```
public function getListCat()
{
    $listCat = $this->asArray()->where(['id_user' => $session->id])->get();
    return $listCat->num_rows();
```

i check "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Result::num_rows()"

How i can get "num_rows()" data in Codeigniter 4?

Comment: What do you get back when you var_dump($listCat); Also something to think about. Are you using the MySQL driver? or the MSSQL driver?

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter 4 doesn't have num_row() function just like codeigniter 3 at the time I answered this question. This is how I check if any data exists.
I am trying to re-modify your code below

```php
public function getListCat()
{
    $listCat = $this->asArray()->where('id_user', $session->id)->countResultAll();
    return $listCat;
}
```

I hope this will work for you else call my attention.

Comment: [`getNumRows()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=getnumrows#getnumrows)

Comment: This was included recently

Answer (score 3):

Boy, I also spent some time researching, but for now, I concluded the following:

According to the framework documentation, there are two methods that it uses to help you count results:

```
$builder->countAllResults();
$builder->countAll();
```

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

However, there are some discussions in the codeigniter forum about the best way to do this, since theoretically, `$builder->countAllResults()` or `CountAll()` would execute another query against the database.

Working for some time with CI4, I noticed a curiosity:
If you call `get()` on your model and on the controller call `$queryVarHoldingModelMethodCall->resultID->num_rows` - it will show the number of lines in the same way! I believe that, in this way, only a query is executed in the database, since the query object you will be able to call in the controller using `$queryVarHoldingModelMethodCall->getRow()` or `$queryVarHoldingModelMethodCall->getResult()`

In your example I would call

```
public function getListCat()
{
    return $this->asArray()->where(['id_user' => $session->id])->get();
}
```

And in your controller you can:

```
$listCatModel     = new \App\Models\ListCatModel(); // call your Model
$listCat          = $listCatModel->getListCat(); // execute method
$listCat_num_rows = $listCat->resultID->num_rows; // num_rows object
$listCatResults   = $listCat->getResult(); // or ->getRow()
```

You can check what values are you passing by:

```
var_dump($listCat);
var_dump($listCat->resultID->num_rows);
var_dump($listCat->getRow());
// exit();
// and maybe an exit(); to stop code execution on your vars values and print them for testing
```

//
Let me know how you did it and if it worked, since we don't have enough documentation so far. I am rewriting my first app from CI3 to CI4 and in general it decreased 1/3 of the original code. Working and looking forward to seeing the end result. Good luck out there! Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You  can change `num_rows()` to `getNumRows` in CI4.
It works same. Beside that, You have to change where to `getwhere`

```
public function getListCat(){
       $listCat = $this->table(your_table)->asArray()->getWhere(['id_user' => $session->id]);
       return $listCat->getNumRows();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since countAllResults also resets any field values that you may have passed to select(), you can simply place false as the first parameter.
countAllResults(false);

ref - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = $this->where('id_user', $session->id)->get();
//print_r($query);
//die;
return $query->getNumRows();
exit;

//num_rows() is depreciated in CI4. Its been changed to getNumRows() and many other query builder classes
```

Ref: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=getnumrows#getNumRows

Comment: If you [edit] your answer to add an explanation, it will make it more valuable to others.

Comment: thanks, am used to finding answers here not providing