# Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::num_rows()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to make a code generator for my table

**Here's my model :**

```
public function buat_kode()   {

    $this->db->table('RIGHT(proses_cutting.kode_packing_list,6) as kode', FALSE);
    $this->builder()->orderBy('kode_packing_list','DESC');    
    $this->builder()->limit(1);    
      $query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting');      //cek dulu apakah ada sudah ada kode di tabel.    
      if ($query->num_rows() <> 0){      
       //jika kode ternyata sudah ada.      
        $data = $query->row();      
        $kode = intval($data->kode) + 1;    
      }
      else {      
       //jika kode belum ada      
        $kode = 1;    
      }

      $kodemax = str_pad($kode, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // angka 4 menunjukkan jumlah digit angka 0
      $kodejadi = "PLIK059".$kodemax;    // hasilnya ODJ-9921-0001 dst.
      return $kodejadi;
    }
```

**controller :**

```
public function create()
{
    session();
    $data = [
        'main' => 'prosescutting/create',
        'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
        'title' => 'Form Tambah Proses Cutting',
        'kodeunik' => $this->pcuttingModel->buat_kode(),
        'kode_packing_list' => $kodePackingSekarang,
    ];
    return view('template/template', $data);
}
```

**and my table :**
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEXyk.png)

What im trying to do is make a generator for  kode_packing_list for each item of nama_barang so when i input another Renata Blouse it will automatically fill with **PLIK059000007**

But when I tried to run it, it show me these errors:

> Error
> Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::num_rows()
> APPPATH\Models\PcuttingModel.php at line 33

and the line 33 is

```
if ($query->num_rows() <> 0){
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong database table functions, try this:

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect(); // optional; init database if not created yet

$builder = $db->table('proses_cutting');
$builder->select('RIGHT(proses_cutting.kode_packing_list,6) as kode');
$builder->orderBy('kode_packing_list','DESC');
$builder->limit(1);

if($builder->countAllResults() > 0) {
    $query = $builder->get();
    $result = $query->getResult(); // Result as objects eg; $result->kode
    $kode = $result->kode;
}

// Other option: I believe you can do this too

$builder = $db->table('proses_cutting');
$builder->select('RIGHT(proses_cutting.kode_packing_list,6) as kode');
$builder->orderBy('kode_packing_list','DESC');
$builder->limit(1);

$query = $builder->get();
$result = $query->getResult('array');
if(is_array($result) && count($array) > 0) {
    $kode = $result['kode'];
}
```

For more information about the builder, see the CI documentation:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: thats fix it, but it make a weird error :
ErrorException #64
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script
APPPATH\Models\PcuttingModel.php at line 3

Comment: Did you (auto)load the database library?

Comment: Which version of CI do you use?

Comment: 4, precisely 4.0.4

Comment: Ah, don't know why... I thought you were using CI 3.x. I updated my answer.

Comment: It works, Thanks.
So all this time you already gave a right answer, just a wrong version. Thanks for the help, really appericiate it.

Answer (score 1):

@SukmaQintara I think this is what you will do. Codeigniter 4 query builder does not really have that method num_row declared but us countResultAll()

Example

```php
      $query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting');      //cek dulu apakah ada sudah ada kode di tabel.    
      if ($query->countResultAll() <> 0){      
       //jika kode ternyata sudah ada.      
        $data = $query->row();      
        $kode = intval($data->kode) + 1;    
      }
      else {      
       //jika kode belum ada      
        $kode = 1;    
      }
```

If it does not work try my other answer[My last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811132/codeigniter-v4-num-rows-call-to-undefined-method/60896476#60896476) OR use the reference document [Check this Document](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count#countAllResults)

Comment: It fix num_row issue, but now **$query->row();** also error, what should i use to read row from my table

Comment: @SukmaQintara I think you assigning the $query to a variable will solve the issue. Example, ``$query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting');`` to fetch data ``$data = $query;``. This should be before the if condition then use this to fetch data ``$data->get()->getRow();``. I haven't text this but hope it will work. Reference https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html and https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/results.html